# Meteor 1.04 function callback on each render

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to have my Material design cards resize based on the highest height of each row (http://tabletlisting.com/). This is the what I'm using in a global helper.

```
Template.registerHelper('setCardHeight',function(tabletCards){
var tabletCount = tabletCards.length;
var tabletCardWidth = 450;
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
var cardsPerRow = Math.floor(screenWidth / tabletCardWidth);
if (cardsPerRow > 1) {
    for (var i=0; i<tabletCount; i+=cardsPerRow) {
        var maxHeight = $(tabletCards[i]).height();
        for (var j=0; j<cardsPerRow; j++) {
            if (j+i < tabletCount) {
                currentCardHeight = $(tabletCards[j+i]).height();
                if (currentCardHeight > maxHeight) {
                    maxHeight = currentCardHeight;
                }
            }
        }
        maxHeight = maxHeight + 10;
        var setHeight = 'height: ' + maxHeight + 'px';
        for (var j=0; j<cardsPerRow; j++) {
            if (j+i < tabletCount) {
                tabletCards[j+i].setAttribute('style', setHeight);
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

This works but I need to have this function call every time one of the filters on the site menu causes the view to change. I tried this in a Template.mytemplate.onRendered but it only calls it on initial load.

```
Template.tabletsList.onRendered(function() {
  var allTabletCards = this.findAll('.tablet-card')
  UI._globalHelpers.setCardHeight(allTabletCards);
});
```

What should I use to have this function callback on each render change after the DOM has loaded. Thanks.

Comment: To improve the lisibility of your code prefer this https://gist.github.com/Rebolon/fadaf1c67799fb6bc54d (not the solution of your problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, have you tried flexbox? Like 3 lines of css & your problem is solved.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If you have to do it with javascript, don't use a helper. Save those for your HTML. 
Instead, set up a dependency in your `onCreated`. Then, stick a `.depend()` in  your function. Then stick that function inside an `autorun`. 
When a filter change occurs, call `dep.changed()`.

If you want to do something less meteoric, just set your function as a callback on a filter change, same thing, just a bit harder to read.

But seriously, give flexbox a shot!

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. I actually got it to work with what I think is a hack. I changed the helper to a handle bar 
    {{setCardHeights tablets}}
and called it after my tablets loop. The key being that in that handlebar call in the html I pass my tablets which is reactive. That causes the handlebar to be called every time my tablets change. Works well but feels like a hack.

Comment: nah that's legit too, helpers don't have to return anything, but for my feeble mind it's tough to remember what I was thinking a month later when I see it...